# Multiple RewriteCond RegEx

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So I have the followings urls

```
foo/
foo/abc/
foo/def/
foo/ghi/
foo/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/
```

and I only want to rewrite the last one(s). The first four (path segments) are fixed.

```
if first path segment is "foo"
and we have a second path segment
and second path segment is not "abc"
and second path segment is not "def"
and second path segment is not "ghi"
then ^foo/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/$ index.php?id=20&alias=$1 [L, QSA]
```

Comment: "Fixed" doesn't by any chance mean, actually exist as directories (whereas everything else doesn't)? Because then you'd probably better off with the `-d` flag (resp. its negation) http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: No, not actual directories. I changed it to "path segments".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^foo/((?!abc|def|ghi)[a-z0-9-]+)/$ index.php?id=20&alias=$1 [L,QSA]
```